# how prority queue can be inserted in this format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

We have an array of 5 elements: [4, 8, 1, 7, 3] and we have to insert all the elements in the
max-priority queue. First as the priority queue is empty, so 4 will be inserted initially.
Now when 8 will be inserted it will move to front as 8 is greater than 4. While inserting 1, as
it is the current minimum element in the priority queue, it will remain in the back of priority
queue. Now 7 will be inserted between 8 and 4 as 7 is smaller than 8.
Now 3 will be inserted before 1 as it is the 2nd minimum element in the priority queue. All
the steps are represented in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to decipher your qn. Is this what you needed?

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

lst = [1,7,5,3,21,9]

q = PriorityQueue()

for items in lst:
    q.put(items)

while not q.empty():
    next_item = q.get()
    print(next_item)
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
21
```

Source:

> https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-python-priority-queu